# What is the equivalent of 'Installer squeaksource' in Pharo?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I want to execute this in the context of Pharo, was initially for Squeak.

```
Installer squeaksource
 project: 'MetacelloRepository';
 install: 'ConfigurationOfMagritte2'.
(Smalltalk at: #ConfigurationOfMagritte2) project latestVersion load: 'Magritte-Seaside'.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code will work:

```
Gofer new 
    squeaksource: 'MetacelloRepository';
    configurationOf: 'Magritte2';
    load.
(Smalltalk at: #ConfigurationOfMagritte2) project latestVersion load: 'Magritte-Seaside'.
```

There are other ways, but this is the most "direct" translation :)

Answer (score 1):

That won't result in working code in a recent version of Pharo. Magritte2 is old and unsupported. Use Magritte3. That is maintained on Smalltalkhub.

Comment: yep, that's also true, but I think he is following the tutorial :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with the same question today, in Pharo 6.x - current (9.0 as of writing):

```
Metacello new
  baseline: 'Magritte';
  repository: 'github://magritte-metamodel/Magritte';
  load
```